# Javascript not giving alert after for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, alert

i have a javascript function which has foor loop in it. once the loop exists it is not displaying alert can anyone suggest what might be wrong.

the code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
<?PHP Include('Includes\common\header_items.php');

session_start();

?>
</head>
<body>

 <form name="step2" method="POST">
<div id="qwe">
<table width="500px" id="myTable" name="myTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>    
                                    <td >Brawing / Document No.</th>
                                    <td>Revision No.</th>
                                    <td>Description     (Optional)</th>                                     
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>    
                                    <td width="40%"><input type="text" id="553" name="2" /></th>
                                    <td width="10%"><input type="text" id="revID553" name="3" /></th>
                                    <td width="45%"><input type="text" id="descpID553" name="4" /></th>                                     
                                </tr>
                            <tr>                                        
                                    <td width="40%"><input type="text" id="4" name="21" /></th>
                                    <td width="10%"><input type="text" id="15" name="31" /></th>
                                    <td width="45%"><input type="text" id="6" name="41" /></th>                                     
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                    <td width="40%"><input type="text" id="556" name="2" /></th>
                                    <td width="10%"><input type="text" id="revID556" name="3" /></th>
                                    <td width="45%"><input type="text" id="descpID556" name="4" /></th>                                     
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

<input type="submit" onclick='Javascript: return testFunc();'>
</div>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
var table_row = [];

function testFunc(){

table_row.length = 0;
var count = 0;


var testing = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("input");

for (i=0; i<=testing.length; i++){
var data = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("input")[i].id;

            if(data.substring(0,2) == "55")
            {

            var value_doc = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value;

            var value_rev = 'revID'+data;               
            var rev = document.getElementById(value_rev).value;

            var value_descp = 'descpID'+data;
            var descp_data = document.getElementById(value_descp).value;


            //code to add into array
            table_row[count] = [data,rev,descp_data];

            count ++;

            }

        }

 alert("I am in the end");

   </script>

   </body>
  </html>
```

i cant figure out why it is not displaying the last alert. Any suggestions? THe last alert is not working.

Comment: is the loop running properly?

Comment: @Bala who told you like that..? You are talking like, you already seen the code inside the for loop that OP didn't display..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy . I am saying code which is posted by OP not full code  see this link http://jsfiddle.net/FhfEF/

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the second alert, and verify that you reach the line?

Comment: this is worked for me `function testFunc(){
    alert("I am in test function");
    for (i=0; i<=5; i++){
     //code to add values in array
     // it displays the values added in array correctly
     alert(i);
    }
   alert("Function is Ending"); //this is not displayed once loop runs 5 times.
   return true;
}
 testFunc();`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy He does't show any code with in the loop .. that s y i said like that ...

Comment: Your code is fine, the code inside the loop might throw an exception which stops the function from running all the way through. I copy-pasted your question code and it runs fine.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with `//code to add values in array // it displays the values added in array correctly`. Also note that your loop is running **six** times, not five times. Maybe that causes an issue.

Comment: i have updated the code. i have checked when i comment everything in for loop then the alert shows, but when i un comment the 1st line i.e.     var data = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("input")[i].id; The alert does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Your code is working fine for me.

Write your function like this.

```
function testFunc(){
    alert("I am in test function");
    for (i=0; i<=5; i++){
     //code to add values in array
     // it displays the values added in array correctly
        alert('call');
    }
   alert("Function is Ending"); //this is not displayed once loop runs 5 times.
   return true;
}
```

Now Call your function in load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     testFunc();
 });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVRkh/)

Comment: i have updated the code, when i comment everything in for loop it works, need to figure out y it is not alerting after for loop with the code. thnx for your help

Comment: the code is working now all i did was changed var data = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("input")[i].id; to var data = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].id;

Answer (score 0):

You have not call your function :

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhfEF/1/)

Check Below Code :

```
function testFunc(){
    alert("I am in test function");
    for (i=0; i<=5; i++){
     //code to add values in array
     // it displays the values added in array correctly
    }
   alert("Function is Ending"); //this is not displayed once loop runs 5 times.
   return true;
}

testFunc(); // calling function
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in extra loop iteration.
I also rewrite code a little bit to avoid many `document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("input")`, because it causes searching over DOM every time it appears.

```
<script language="javascript">
var table_row = [];

function testFunc() {

    table_row.length = 0;
    var count = 0;

    var testing = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (i = 0; i < testing.length; i++) {
        var data = testing[i].id;
        if (data.substring(0,2) == "55") {
            var value_doc = testing[i].value;

            var value_rev = 'revID' + data;               
            var rev = document.getElementById(value_rev).value;

            var value_descp = 'descpID' + data;
            var descp_data = document.getElementById(value_descp).value;

            //code to add into array
            table_row[count] = [data, rev, descp_data];

            count ++;
        }
    }
    alert("I am in the end");
}
</script>
```

Comment: the code is working now all i did was changed var data = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("input")[i].id; to var data = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].id;

Comment: @Alz your idea is not correct: you will proceed `<input type="submit" onclick='Javascript: return testFunc();'>` as last iteration, which is, I suppose, not good at all

Comment: @Alz I suggest what I have already written in my answer. As minimum, you should replace `i<=testing.length` with `i<testing.length`, because otherwise when in last loop's iteration `i` equals `testing.length`, you will get out of array's (`testing`) bounds